# Confused regarding ForeignKey relationship in Django

Tags: python, django, database, database-design

I'm building a Django app for a blogging platform. While writing the models, I got stuck in the confusion between database relationships.

In my blog, two of my model classes are 'Author' and 'Article'. A particular article is written by a single/unique author. But, one 'Author' writes several articles.

```
class Article(models.Model):
      author_name = models.ForeignKey(Author)
```

Now I also want to store all articles written by a particular author inside the 'Author' class so that I can display them in the 'Author' page in my views.

How do I create the Author model?

```
class Author(models.Model):
     published_articles = ?
```

Comment: Django already provides this functionality: `author.article_set.all()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just add a method to your Author model to retrieve all of his articles easily from a view?

```
class Article(models.Model):
    author_name = models.ForeignKey(Author)

class Author(models.Model):
    # ...
    def get_articles(self):
         "Returns the author published articles"
         return self.article_set.all()
```

Then, in your view

```
def my_view(request):

    # Retrieve the author the way you see fit
    author = Author.objects.get(id=request.session['author'])

    articles = author.get_articles()
    context = {"articles": articles}
    return render(request, 'mytemplate.html', context)
```

I suggest you take a look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/), since they clearly demonstrate with amazing exactitude how you should handle your problem.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution (if you actually want to save that relation):

As stated [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#recursive-relationships):

> If you need to create a relationship on a model that has not yet been defined, you can use the name of the model, rather than the model object itself.

```
class Author(models.Model):
     published_articles = models.ManyToManyField('your_actual_app_label.Article')
```

## Solution (if you only want a way to access published_articles of author):

And as stated [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#related-objects):

> Django also creates API accessors for the “other” side of the relationship – the link from the related model to the model that defines the relationship. For example, a **Blog** object **b** has access to a list of all related **Entry** objects via the **entry_set** attribute: **b.entry_set.all()**.

```
author = Author.objects.first()
author.article_set.all()
```

Choose Wisely. 
Hope this helps :)

Comment: The ForeignKey (Author) field in class Article will remain as is?

Comment: Thanks a lot man! But can you explain the solutions, if possible.

Comment: This is not good practice, since it's not a many to many relationship.

Comment: @HarshGupta I've updated the answer. choose according to your use case.

Comment: @FelixD. it depends on the use case, an article may be authored by many authors. in that case foreign key relation won't be required. Best!!

Comment: Yes, but @HarshGupta specified it's a one to many relationship... But I understand your point.